# Where are the official i18n WordPress versions stored (SVN)?

Tags: localization, svn

I've already checked http://i18n.svn.wordpress.org/, but something seems off. I need official file checksums.

I took `/ar` (Arabic) as an example, and compared all the files in the repository against the files that I downloaded from http://ar.wordpress.org/, and they don't match (specifically, wp-content/languages/ar.po and ar.mo files). Also, the `/ar/trunk` and `/ar/tags/4.1` directories are pretty much empty. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## i18n resource ... the hide & seek game

<strike>Note up front: I'm not 100% sure about this, so please take the following with a grain of salt.</strike>

I'm 99% sure by now, that the following information is correct. (Still, it's confusing even after years with WordPress).

---

#### Non-Gettext translation for core

The `18n.wordpress.org` resource is used by the [Glotpress project](https://translate.wordpress.org/projects). There you can [find nearly all languages](https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp/dev) for **the files that are not translatable with Gettext** and look at the [language completion status](https://translate.wordpress.org/languages). This means: `wp-config-sample.php`, `readme.txt`, `license.txt` and some messages, etc. are translated there

#### Gettext translation for core

When you look at the [WordPress APIs page](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress.org_API), then you will find [the **Translation** section](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress.org_API#Translations) as well. There you will find not only pointers core, but for all wp.org hosted plugins and themes as well. When you ping

```
https://api.wordpress.org/translations/core/1.0/?version={wp-version}
```

you will get back a JSON response (example for [WP v4.1.1](https://api.wordpress.org/translations/core/1.0/?version=4.1.1)). Example output (shortened):

```
{
    "translations" : [ 
        {
            "language"     : "ar",
            "version"      : "4.1.1",
            "updated"      : "2015-01-17 19:01:24",
            "english_name" : "Arabic",
            "native_name"  : "\u0627\u0644\u0639\u0631\u0628\u064a\u0629",
            "package"      : "https:\/\/downloads.wordpress.org\/translation\/core\/4.1.1\/ar.zip",
            "iso"          : {
                "1" : "ar",
                "2" : "ara"
            },
            "strings"      : { 
                "continue" : "\u0627\u0644\u0645\u062a\u0627\u0628\u0639\u0629"
            }
        },
        // ... other languages here
```

The `language` and `iso` will be of the following

> The repository contains directories for each locale, which are named as follows:
>
> - ISO 639 language code (lowercase) or
> - ISO 639 language code (lowercase) + an underscore + ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code (uppercase) or
> - ISO 639-3 language code (lowercase)

*Quote: [Repo file structure on Glotpress](https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/handbook/translating/working-with-the-translation-repository/#repository-file-structure) - props [Dominik "@ocean90" Schilling](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/40969/ocean90) for fixing this in the GlotPress docs.*

The "ISO 639" (and it's used parts 1 & 2) are the international bibliographic language and country codes. [@StephenHarris](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/9364/stephen-harris) and me are maintaining the "WCM User Language Switcher" with its break out project, the ["ISO 639-1/2"](https://github.com/wecodemore/ISO_639-2) JSON source (afaik, there's only this one on the internets) which you can take to verify parts of the JSON return.

> Every language code present in the two-letter code set has a corresponding language code in the alpha-3 list, but not necessarily vice versa. ISO 639-2:1998 provides two sets of three-letter alphabetic codes for the representation of names of languages, one for terminology applications and the other for bibliographic applications. The code sets are the same except for twenty-five languages that have variant language codes because of the criteria used for formulating them.

### Checksums

There's also an official API endpoint for checksums in your language:

```
https://api.wordpress.org/core/checksums/1.0/?version={version_number}&locale={iso_code}
```

Just fill `iso_code` with `de_DE` for example.

The returned JSON will look like the following:

```
{
    "checksums" : {
        "wp-settings.php" : "c4833959e93d9368a35712e52c57c650",
        "wp-cron.php"     : "cf2ae664186202bf6944c31378ec5af9",
        // ...
```

That's it.

**Edit**: I just looked at `~/wp-admin/includes/update-core.php` and the `update_core()` version and it seems that we got a `global $wp_local_page` global as well. There you will as well find the [`get_core_checksums()` function](http://queryposts.com/function/get_core_checksums/).

> Gets and caches the checksums for the given version of WordPress.
>
> `@return boolean|array False on failure. An array of checksums on success.`

This is how core is using it inside `update_core()`:

```
$cs = get_core_checksums( $wp_version, isset( $wp_local_package ) ? $wp_local_package : 'en_US' );
```

### The WordPress version

The WordPress version can be obtained from the `$GLOBALS['wp_version']`. Make sure that you use a stable version and don't try this on trunk where you will find stuff like `'4.2-alpha-31531'` while the current version is `4.1.1`. Which obviously will return ... nothing.

### Issues with the WordPress Internal Updater

One more issue: If you just download translation files as outlined above and [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language#Manually_Installing_Language_Files) but not a complete localized package the updater might start bugging you to update even if your files are already up to date. This is due to localized packages setting the global variable `$wp_local_package`. For more details have a look at [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157729/after-updating-wp-keeps-nagging-about-a-newer-version-why).

### Quick example

To give a more WordPress-y touch to those WordPress structures, just fetch the resources with the WP HTTP API. I wrote plenty of example answers: [Link to SERP here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A385+is%3Aanswer+remote). You might want to perform a `wp_remote_head()` request to check if a file exists before fetching it.

### i18n files via ... Composer!

And then - as [fellow Austrian @kraftner](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/47733/kraftner) pointed out - [there, on Koodimonni in Finland](http://languages.koodimonni.fi/), you will find a Satis repo updated every 30 minutes. More info when you follow the link. Hint: Prefer this source if you are trying to setup WP. Else prefer the above when building remote requests or plugin stuff yourself.

Comment: Thanks for this great and detailed post.  

Does that mean there is no centralized way to access the official localized files only but to extract the official `.zip` files? The `sr_RS` (Serbian) localized files for instance are accessible via SVN, which is great, but `ar` (Arabic) aren't, so I assume those are managed separately. Does that mean that the translation teams themselves build the `.zip` files?

Comment: @GrayFox That means that _each_ translation team builds its _own_, localized "Non-Gettext" versions and bundles them as `*.zip` files and delivers them via `18n.svn.wordpress.org`. And that means every translation relies on just some people. The `.po` files still are accessible via `api.wordpress.org` remote access (JSON), but again come as `*.zip` file when you request it.